# Is this code valid C++?

Tags: c++, declaration, definition

Is the following code valid C++?

```
const int  var = 10;
{ 
   int  var[var]; // why doesn't this give any error ?
}
```

Note : The code compiles on my g++ compiler.

Answer (score 19):

As-is?  No.  If it were in the body of a function?  Yes.

The first line declares an integer constant named `var` with a value of `10`.

The braces begins a new block.  Within that block, a new variable is declared, named `var`, which is an array of `int` with a size equal to the value of the integer constant previously declared as `var` (`10`).

The key is that `var` refers to the first variable until *after* the second variable named `var` is fully declared.  Between the semicolon following the second declaration and the closing brace, `var` refers to the second variable.  (If there was an initializer for the second variable, `var` would begin to refer to the second variable immediately before the  initializer.)

Comment: Lol -- +1 for the "in the body of a function" bit :P

Comment: @Billy:  Well, I think that's somewhat important; if this code were at namespace or class scope you'd have to make the block a namespace or class or function or something...

Comment: @James McNellis: name hiding, or one of my most hated features. You can spend hours trying to understand what's wrong...

Comment: @Matthieu: If you're ever in a scenario where names are being hidden, 1. that is easy to see (names are duplicated), and 2. it's an indication that the function or method you're working in is too long. Maybe if you're referring to hiding *inherited* names you'd have a case....

Comment: @Matthieu:  Maybe.  I would have agreed two months ago, but recently I've been learning C# and it has very stringent rules concerning when names can be reused (for example, `for (int i = ...) { } int i;` is not allowed, which combined with a few other annoyances has driven me absolutely nuts :-)).

Comment: @Billy: It's supposed to be obvious, yet it's easy to use `i`, `it` or `end` and it get very confusing. However Python is even worse in this department with its absence of scoping so it's not that bad. @James: this is crazy, since there's no hiding going on.

Comment: @Matthieu:  Actually, I shouldn't be too critical of that feature; I'm just having a hard time giving up C++ and I'm hypercritical of all things related to managed code :-D.  In reality I think what they've done is actually very good:  the rule is that you can't reuse a name in nested scopes (so `for (int i = ...) { } for (int i = ...) { }` would be okay but the above example is not).  That prevents name hiding and is consistent and easy to remember (how many C++ rules are consistent and easy to remember?  :-P).

Answer (score 5):

Yes the code is valid C++. Non-local `var` is visible up to the point of declaration of local `var`.

So `int var[var]` defines a local array of 10 integers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the code is valid C++
It is a concept of SCOPE : Hiding Names

```
 const int  var = 10;
  { 
   int  var[var]; // why doesn't this give any error ?
  }
```

I think this link clears your doubt

IN C++:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/9a9h7328%28v=VS.80%29.aspx

In C :

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fzexscope_c.htm

If u want deep knowledge On this : Go for this link,here the information is about Lexical versus dynamic scoping

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28programming%29

but in your code : "Scope  **::**" of visibility  of **var** .Here It differs like local and non-local variable.
Inside braces **{ x=1; }** local variable . where as here {y=1;**{x=1;}**} ,here it differs.

helpful links

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b7kfh662%28VS.80%29.aspx

http://www.awitness.org/delphi_pascal_tutorial/c++_delphi/c++_scope_variables.html

Comment: @BE :I think the first 3 links which gave is clear.about this example>The ramining no need